# Python: which module is for reading data from a 2D curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

It is a very difficult problem for me.

For example I have a picture as input file. [image]

**Please be noted that I just have this picture and nothing more.**

I want to read the data from the blue curve. So that I can eg. input the x and get the y as the result.

As a python beginner, I could also imagine that the module could read the color. So that if I input the x, only the blue y is read.

I would like to know which python module is suitable for such job? Or, if this task is too difficult for python, which programm language is suitble? Thanks for your help!

Comment: PIL might be useful.

Comment: This task is not too difficult for any programming language. As far as libraries, what did Google tell you?

Comment: @0605002 Thanks. But I didnot found similar usages from the PIL module.

Comment: @Soviut I only know the method if the data or formel are known, and the curve is the one to be made.

Comment: Import the PIL module
Read the image data into memory with the .load method
You can determine the color of pixels from the returned pix[,] array
You could also filter the image data so that only blue pixels remain visible
More difficult is to detect the x-axis scaling automatically. If the x-axis has different numbers on it every time, you either have to tell the Python script the range of those numbers or write a - more complicated - function that does optical character recognition on your image.
Then you can write a "lookup" function that takes "x" as an argument, and retrieves the y.

Comment: Do you have a lot of pictures to analyze or it's just this single one?

Comment: @Yugi I actually want a general method for such kind  of job.

Comment: @Ukimiku Thanks for the programming hint. It sounds very complex for me. Would you please give me some code structure for this kind of task? Thanks.

Comment: @doglas. I think it would be better if you came up with a kind of top-down code skeleton. Then you may get hints and help fleshing that one out. Although I am an experienced programmer, the task is complex for me, too. Especially as you are after a general method, which would doubtlessly involve optical character recognition. The rest is easy, but I have never programmed OCR routines. Do you know if the font used in the image for numbers is always the same (same text height, weight...) or will it change from image to image?